# Values for parameterised queries

Tags: sql

I have a SQL statement String in Java which contains, among other things, the segment:

```
" AND \"Reference_No\" > ? "
```

I understand that this is a parameterized query, where the statement is precompiled and the parameters then added, in order to prevent injection attacks.

However, every example I've seen of this used, I have always seen accompanying code where the parameter values are then hard-coded in using some kind of setter method with code that runs something like:

```
setValue(1, "value1");
```

The program I am trying to understand does not appear to have this accompanying code, and I am trying to understand at what point a value is added to this SQL statement.

The application which uses this is a webUI servlet that sends and receives job transactions. More specifically, I am looking at the page that lists pending transactions.

I have a method which contains the following:

```
List<Job> query = getJdbcTemplate().query(sql.toString(), 
                                          new Object[]{minRef}, 
                                          rowMapper);
```

sql contains the SQL statement segment in question.

Is the value-adding dealt with by the JdbcTemplate class? If so, how does it determine the values?

Comment: The parameter binding is done in the `query` method of the Spring JDBC template.

Comment: Is there any way to view the source code for the `query` method?

Comment: I am sure there is. Search around, I don't know where exactly it is.